# Crash during stream materialization with OpenCV BackgroundSubtractorMOG2 with Akka streams in Java

Tags: java, opencv, akka, video-processing, akka-stream

for my project I want to create an application that does some video analysis with OpenCV libs in Java while using Akka streams.

I tried using the BGsubtractorMOG2 in a separate project that doesn't use Akka streams and everything works fine, but now when I materialize my stream with a stage containing the MOG2 function my program crashes. I am sure that the problem is in MOG2 because if I try to remove it and just capture and show frames on video everything works fine.

here is some of the code inside an akka actor

```
private final Materializer materializer = 
ActorMaterializer.create(this.getContext());
private final BackgroundSubtractorMOG2 mog2 = Video.createBackgroundSubtractorMOG2();
```

this gets executed in a preStart() method
the following creates an akka stream source that generates frames with openCV VideoCapture

```
this.frameSource = Source.fromGraph(new CameraFrameSource(capture));
```

this is the middle part of the stream where I want the video analysis to be done; it creates a copy of the frame, one goes through the video analysis and the other goes untouched into a zip and waits to its copy to be processed by HOG2

```
this.videoAnalysisPartialGraph = GraphDSL.create(builder -> {
        final UniformFanOutShape<Mat, Mat> A = builder.add(Broadcast.create(2));
        final FlowShape<Mat, Mat> bgs = builder.add(Flow.of(Mat.class).map(
        f -> {return subtractBackground(f); }).async());
        final FanInShape2<Mat, Mat, Pair<Mat, Mat>> zip = 
            builder.add(ZipWith.create((Mat left, Mat right) -> {
            return new Pair<Mat, Mat>(left, right);
        }));

        builder.from(A).toInlet(zip.in1());
        builder.from(A).via(bgs).toInlet(zip.in0());

        return new FlowShape<Mat, Pair<Mat, Mat>>(A.in(), zip.out());

    });
```

this is the substraction method that makes the program crash when it gets materialized and starts running

```
private Mat subtractBackground(Mat frame){
    Mat fgmask = new Mat();
    this.mog2.apply(frame, fgmask);
    return fgmask;
}
```

this is the closed graph created for debugging purposes that gets materialized once the actor receives a message that simply picks 33 frames each second and process them in stages creating a pair of Mat, then one of the two Mat in the pair is picked and showed in a window, the killswitch part is there to help me turn off the stream, not sure if it's actually needed, but doesn't bother since the stream works when there is no MOG2 involved

```
this.stream = frameSource.throttle(33, FiniteDuration.create(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS), 1, ThrottleMode.shaping())
            .via(this.videoAnalysisPartialGraph).map(p -> p.first()).viaMat(KillSwitches.single(), Keep.right())
            .toMat(Sink.foreach(f -> showFrame(f)), Keep.left());
```

this is the method that runs the stream

```
private void startVideoCapture() {
    this.capture.open(cameraId);
    if (capture.isOpened()) {
        this.cameraActive = true;
        killswitch = this.stream.run(materializer);

    } else {
        System.err.println("Can't open camera connection.");
    }
}
```

As I said the stream works perfectly when I don't do background subtraction and I just show the captured video on screen, going trhough the same stream graph (modified to not include hog2 of course).

Does it have something to do with dispatchers/materializator? I have no idea, does anyone have any suggestion?

Thank you

EDIT:
I tried applying MOG2 outside of the stream but still inside the AKKA actor and still the program crashes. So now I think that could be something related to how an Akka actor deals with the MOG2.apply call.

Answer (score 0):

**WORKAROUND**

I solved the problem after I found that there was a conflict between OpenCV libs and akka-remote libs, for the moment I removed the latter and everything works correctly.
I may need to use both libs together in the future so at the moment I still don't know how to completely solve this